# Add a custom dashboard to a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I need to build a dashboard that will allow users to sign in/out and access/update their business account information.

WordPress has its own dashboard for publishing content but this is not what I am looking for.

Would it be easier for me to create a second site using a framework (Ruby on Rails) that makes this type of user access easier? Or is there a solution in WordPress that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily customize the existing WordPress dashboard. The items shown on the dashboard are determined by the function current_user_can(), so you can hide items by restricting the capabilities of the user using the function add_role(). You can add your own items by the function add_submenu_page().

It has been a while since I customized the WordPress dashboard but if I remember correctly I also had to use JavaScript and CSS to dynamically modify the DOM but this may be because I was doing something unusual. Anyway I think it was quite easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can check out the following wordpress plugin for your requirement
https://wordpress.org/plugins/client-dash/